# How to Exclude indexing menu in Google Custom Search

Tags: html, seo

Hi I am using Google Custom Search for searching content in my website.

However when searching a word, google can't exclude the menu from the page, for example
http://www.innosia.com/Home/ArticleSearch?q=efore&sitesearch=innosia.com

If you see efore, every page will show up because each page contains a link to Efore page. How do I tell Google to exclude the link area (left and right menu) and only index the title and content area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the same information... It took me a while but I found this in the Google Custom Search documentation. This Google article explains exactly how to acheive what you want:

http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2364585&ctx=cb&src=cb&cbid=4iiarmion6fw&cbrank=1

Enjoy!

Comment: link is broken :(

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answers (Jeremiah) link referred to adding  although this no longer works as explained here: https://support.google.com/programmable-search/thread/16487981?hl=en. In this answer there is also a workaround to your issue.

Currently there are no quick easy methods to hide content within a page in google search, only to hide a whole page.

More reading here:
https://www.seroundtable.com/google-no-block-indexing-parts-pages-29144.html

[Is there a way to prevent Googlebot from indexing certain parts of a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497445/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-googlebot-from-indexing-certain-parts-of-a-page)